# Oracle : Inner join gives Invalid number error whereas Left join returns rows successfully

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am joining two views. If I use an inner join I get an ORACLE error : Invalid Number. However if I use left join or right join I do not get any error.

Comment: Please post some code, some data, table structure...

Comment: The table has around 2 million records. The key I am using to join are both of type NUMBER(10)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could start by posting the code that's working with outer joins but not with the inner join. (Unless it's 2000 lines of code... if it is perhaps you can isolate a snippet where you can reproduce the problem, but is only a moderate length.)

Comment: Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details about writing a good question

Comment: When I do :
select count(1) from dbo.view_1 v1, view_2 v2
where v1.id = v2.id -- returns number of rows
when I do
select v1.* from dbo.view_1 v1, view_2 v2
where v1.id = v2.id -- returns rows
but when I do :
select v2.* from dbo.view_1 v1, view_2 v2
where v1.id = v2.id -- gives the invalid number error

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get it with the inner join but not the outer is because the execution paln changes. The "bad" data element may not even be in your result set but in order to find your data, with one plan it has to be read and with the other it doesn't.

Finding the problem record may not be easy.
First, look for joins of different data types and explicit datatype conversions in your view definitions. If you find them - use a conversion function and force full scan with ORDER BY.
Once you identify the problem table, use filters to cut the range until you zero in on the problem record.